# MAC OS X Yosemite App crashing while loading

Tags: crash, osx-yosemite

I have just upgraded one of my MAC bookpro to MAC Yosemite.
When I try to install an app which is basically built on Xcode 3.2.6 it has got crashed. I'm not sure the crash is meant for code complied in 3.2.6 or something else.
I know it is bit old combination having Yosemite and app developed in Xcode 3.2.6 and 10.4u SDK, but we need to do it.
I have collected the crash log and it seems like below. Could anyone tell me what is the exact problem from the crash log? I cannot able to decrypt what this crash log means. If anyone tel me what is going on it would be great help to me

Another info is when I try installing the Xcode 3.2.6 and 10.4u on yosemite it installed but the XCode app symbol got blocked, i could not able to start the xcode itself. Need advice on this as well

Thanks in Advance,
Saravana

```
Process:               CCAAgent [282]
Path:                  /Applications/CCAAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/CCAAgent
Identifier:            com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent
Version:               4.9.5.1
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           CCAAgent [282]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-07-24 22:29:34.747 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A238x)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        2C41B0C2-75AC-0B5D-6435-99E4F7DF5556


Time Awake Since Boot: 110 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000088fa4000

VM Regions Near 0x88fa4000:
    MALLOC_LARGE           0000000008fa3000-0000000088fa4000 [  2.0G] rw-/rwx SM=PRV 
-->
    __TEXT                 000000008fe1f000-000000008fe53000 [  208K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x963511b0 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$sse42 + 192
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation              0x928261e2 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 3010
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation              0x928406df CFStringCreateWithSubstring + 495
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation              0x9289a173 -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 307
4   com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent                0x00016bb2 +[CCALog getThreadNumber:] + 145
5   com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent                0x00017173 +[CCALog createLogFromSourceCode:lineNumber:withLevel:withPrivacy:andStringFormat:] + 446
6   com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent                0x00028cfa GetMacOSVersionString + 211
7   com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent                0x00015965 -[AppMainController init] + 79
8   com.apple.AppKit                    0x9a141e06 -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 380
9   com.apple.AppKit                    0x9a141c18 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 319
10  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a68d29f -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 450`enter code here`
11  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a141237 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 56
12  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a13513e loadNib + 462
13  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a72dcf6 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 330
14  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a72e4e2 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoadingInternal) _loadNibFile:externalNameTable:options:withZone:] + 161
15  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a3922af +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 67
16  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a1345e2 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 745
17  com.apple.AppKit                   0x9a12fbe0 NSApplicationMain + 690
18  com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent               0x000036fa main + 470
19  com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent               0x000032ee _start + 216

20  com.cisco.cca.CCAAgent               0x00003215 start + 41
```

============================

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <time.h>

#import "RC4.h"

#define NSLogSecuredString(level,s,...) [CCALog createLogFromSourceCode:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ withLevel:level withPrivacy:LOG_PRIVACY_ENCRYPTED andStringFormat:(s),##__VA_ARGS__]
#define NSLogSecuredString(level,s,...) [CCALog createLogFromSourceCode:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ withLevel:level withPrivacy:LOG_PRIVACY_ENCRYPTED andStringFormat:(s),##__VA_ARGS__]

#define LOG_LEVEL_ALL   10
#define LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 100     // Debug info
#define LOG_LEVEL_WARN  200     // Warning info
#define LOG_LEVEL_ERROR 300     // Error info
#define LOG_LEVEL_INFO  1000    // System information

#define LOG_PRIVACY_CLEARTEXT   1   // Log is in clear text
#define LOG_PRIVACY_ENCRYPTED   2   // Log is encrypted

@interface CCALog : NSObject 
{
}

+ (void)initialize;
+ (void)setAcceptLogLevel:(NSString*)newLogLevelString withEncryptedLogFilePath:(const char*)encryptedLogPath;
+ (void)setMaxLogSize:(int)newMaxLogSize;
+ (void)dealloc;
+ (int)m_CurrentLogLevel;
+ (void)setCurrentLogLevel:(int)newLogLevel;

+ (void)createLogFromSourceCode:(char*)sourceFile lineNumber:(int)lineNumber withLevel:(int)level withPrivacy:(int)privacy andStringFormat:(const char *)format, ...;


@end



//=====================================================================================================================
// Get the current thread number
//=====================================================================================================================
+ (NSInteger)getThreadNumber:(NSThread*)thread
{
    NSString*   threadString;
    NSRange     numRange;
    NSUInteger  numLength;

    // Somehow there doesn't seem to be an listOfArgumentsI call to return the
    // threadnumber only the name of the thread can be returned but this is NULL
    // if it is not set first!
    // Here is a bit of code to extract the thread number out of the string
    // an NSThread returns when you ask its description to be printed out
    // by NSLog. The format looks like:
    //     <NSThread: 0x10113a0>{name = (null), num = 1}
    // Basically I search for the "num = " substring, copy the remainder
    // excluding the '}' which gives me the threadnumber.
    threadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thread];

    numRange = [threadString rangeOfString:@"num = "];

    numLength = [threadString length] - numRange.location - numRange.length;
    numRange.location = numRange.location + numRange.length;
    numRange.length   = numLength - 1;

    threadString = [threadString substringWithRange:numRange];
    return [threadString intValue];
}



//=====================================================================================================================
// Save a log (a public method)
//=====================================================================================================================
+(void)createLogFromSourceCode:(char*)sourceFile lineNumber:(int)lineNumber withLevel:(int)level withPrivacy:(int)privacy andStringFormat:(const char *)format, ...
{
    NSString *logPrefix, *logPostfix;

    // Do we need to log this event?
    if(level < m_CurrentLogLevel)
        // No, the log level is lower than our required level
        return;

    // Creating prefix and postfix strings
    switch(level)
    {
        case LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG:
            logPrefix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d> [DEBUG]:",[self getThreadNumber:[NSThread currentThread]]];
            break;

        case LOG_LEVEL_WARN:
            logPrefix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d> [WARN]:",[self getThreadNumber:[NSThread currentThread]]];
            break;

        case LOG_LEVEL_ERROR:
            logPrefix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d> [ERROR]:",[self getThreadNumber:[NSThread currentThread]]];
            break;

        case LOG_LEVEL_INFO:
            logPrefix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d> [INFO]:",[self getThreadNumber:[NSThread currentThread]]];
            break;

        default:
            logPrefix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d> [UNKNOWN]:",[self getThreadNumber:[NSThread currentThread]]];
            break;
    }

    // Create a NSString for the source filename with full path
    NSString* srcFile=[NSString stringWithCString:sourceFile];
    // Create a scanner 
    //NSRange srcFileRange=[logPostfix rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"] options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    //logPrefix=[logPostfix substringFromIndex:srcFileRange.location];
    // Get path components in an array
    NSArray *pathComponents = [srcFile pathComponents];
    srcFile=[pathComponents objectAtIndex:[pathComponents count]-1];
    // Create a postfix string to show the source and line#
    logPostfix=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@#%d):",srcFile, lineNumber];

    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, format);
    [self saveLogWithLevel:level withPrivacy:privacy andPrefix:[logPrefix UTF8String] andPostfix:[logPostfix UTF8String] andFormat:format andList:argp];
    va_end(argp);
}

@end
```

=============================================================

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSThread* thread=NSThread:currentThread; // throws compilation error "Expected expression before thread"
    NSRange     numRange;
    NSUInteger  numLength;
    NSString* threadString=@"";
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");



    threadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thread];

    numRange = [threadString rangeOfString:@"num = "];

    numLength = [threadString length] - numRange.location - numRange.length;
    numRange.location = numRange.location + numRange.length;
    numRange.length   = numLength - 1;

    threadString = [threadString substringWithRange:numRange];

    NSLog(@"%s",threadString);


    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `CCALog` class?

Comment: The one thing I am looking for are differences in values generated for thread info or OS version info provided under Yosemite from those under < 10.9 that your logging framework cannot cope with and you are therefore parsing them incorrectly.  I would suggest visual inspection of values (`NSLog()`) and a generous use of `NSAssert`s to ensure you are getting what you expect.

Comment: how to remove this basic error??NSThread* thread=NSThread:currentThread; // throws compilation error "Expected expression before thread"

Comment: It should be `NSThread* thread=[NSThread currentThread]`.

Comment: It is throwing some junk value. @^s#^ similar to this when i print the NSLog(@"%s", threadString)

Comment: Hi Droppy, Thanks for lead me in a right direction... Now I have got an error saying __NSCFString subStringWithRange: Range {xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx} out of bounds; string length 48. this wil become exception for apps linked after 10.10 and iOS8

Comment: Hi Team, I have found the difference between the earlier version and the current version.

Till MAC 10.9 the output would be like 

    "<NSThread: 0x10113a0>{name = (null), num = 1}" 

From MAC 10.10. it has been changed as 

    "<NSThread: 0x10113a0>{number = 1, name = (null)}"

Since the out is not validated it failed. but when I validated it is still failing, 
        threadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thread];
 if(([threadString rangeOfString:@"number = "].location != NSNotFound)||([threadString rangeOfString:@"num"].location!=NSNotFound))
 {
  isFound = 1;
 }

Answer (score 0):

try installing this version of java from apple [1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

as it appears to trigger an other update for what i suspect are the new X11 style command line tools.